# Python requests module, need to encode the body, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, request

I was struggling with sending a request to a web service using the requests module. I'm using Python 3.5.1-32 bit on Windows.

Whenever I request something that contains, for example, a latin accented character such as "á" then I need to encode my string variable explicitly as utf-8. Can someone explain why I need to do this?

Here is my code example:

```
import requests

headers = { "content-type" : "text/xml;charset=UTF-8" }
url = '....'
body = 'á'
requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
```

This doesn't work, the server receives an escaped version of the character, but if I add this before the request:

```
body = body.encode(encoding='utf-8')
```

It works.

Can somebody explain why this is necessary? My Python-Fu is such that it took me a good while to figure this out.

Comment: Actually it should not be necessary. I alway send str() and never bytes().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**requests** doc says:

```
:param data: (optional) Dictionary, bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
```

In **Python 3** `body='á'` is a unicode string. With the method `encode()` you are converting it to bytes.

For a unicode string, **requests** understands it as file content and encodes with *octet-stream/base64*. The false content will be transferred.

*P/S: It's only for **Python 3**. `str` of Python 2 isn't like `str` in Python 3*

Comment: Thanks, I kind of understand that. I assumed that unicode == utf-8 in python 3

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. How do I solve it for Python 2?

Comment: @kev it's difficult to slove your problem, without to see some parts of your code.

Comment: `requests` does not encode `str` as `application/octet-stream`. It encodes it as Latin-1, which is default for HTTP. (If this is impossible, it will fail.) It does not set the content type header. You probably see `application/octet-stream` and `base64`  because you are testing this against `httpbin`. But this is just how `httpbin` sends back the received data, not what it actually received.